# проблема скрапинга сайта python requests

Tags: python, http, https, requests

Всем привет,
пытаюсь получить данные о полетах с сайта

https://www.biman-airlines.com/bookings/flight_selection.aspx

для примера, выбираю Dhaka(DAC) to Sylhet(ZYL), после нажатия кнопки search происходит переход на

https://www.biman-airlines.com/bookings/flight_selection.aspx?TT=RT&SS=&RT=&FL=on&DC=DAC&AC=ZYL&AM=2018-01&AD=09&DC=&AC=&AM=&AD=&DC=&AC=&AM=&AD=&DC=&AC=&AM=&AD=&RM=2018-01&RD=10&PA=1&PT=&PC=&PI=&CC=&NS=&CD=&FS=B4B9631

и отображается информация о полетах, судя по всему, сначала идет запрос на https://www.biman-airlines.com/bookings/captcha.aspx а потом уже основной запрос: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
поэтому я сначала пытаюсь вытащить cookie из первого head запроса

Затем я пытаюсь получить эту страницу, но с помощью python requests:

```
sess = requests.Session()
head = sess.head('https://www.biman-airlines.com/bookings/captcha.aspx', headers=HEADERS)

print 'cookies', requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(sess.cookies)

request = sess.get(
    'https://www.biman-airlines.com/bookings/flight_selection.aspx?TT=RT&SS=&RT=&FL=on&DC=DAC&AC=ZYL&AM=2018-01&AD=09&DC=&AC=&AM=&AD=&DC=&AC=&AM=&AD=&DC=&AC=&AM=&AD=&RM=2018-01&RD=10&PA=1&PT=&PC=&PI=&CC=&NS=&CD=&FS=',
    headers=head.headers, cookies=head.cookies)

print request.text
```

но это не срабатывает, запрос вместо информации о полетах выдает начальную страницу поиска билетов

что я делаю не так? заранее спасибо за советы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге необходимо было добавить в хедеры первого HEAD запроса:

```
'X-Hash-Validate': 'TT=RT&DC=DAC&AC=ZYL&AM=2018-01&AD=09&RM=2018-01&RD=10&FL=on&PA=1&PT=&PC=&PI=&CC=&CD=',
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
```